# How do I merge 2 separate key value pairs inside the same dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have one dictionary with 2 separate key-value pairs and I want to merge them into 1 list with separate dictionaries for all key-value pairs.

Example Input:

`{'Boys': [72, 68, 70, 69, 74], 'Girls': [63, 65, 69, 62, 61]}`

Example Output:

`[{'Boys': 72,'Girls': 63}, {'Boys': 68, 'Girls': 65}, {'Boys': 70, 'Girls': 69}, {'Boys': 69, 'Girls': 62}, {‘Boys’:74,'‘Girls':61]`

I tried looping over the dictionary but I was unable to create a single list out of it.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: hi! it would be helpful if you also post the code that you already have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
my_dict = {'Boys': [72, 68, 70, 69, 74], 'Girls': [63, 65, 69, 62, 61]}
new = [{'Boys': x, 'Girls': y} for x, y in zip(my_dict['Boys'], my_dict['Girls'])]
print(new)
[{'Boys': 72, 'Girls': 63}, {'Boys': 68, 'Girls': 65}, {'Boys': 70, 'Girls': 69}, {'Boys': 69, 'Girls': 62}, {'Boys': 74, 'Girls': 61}]
```

Or a simpler version:

```py
new = []
for boy, girl in zip(my_dict['Boys'], my_dict['Girls']):
    new.append({'Boys': boy, 'Girls': girl})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dict1={'Boys': [72, 68, 70, 69, 74], 'Girls': [63, 65, 69, 62, 61]}
list1=[{'Boys':i,'Girls':j} for i,j in zip(dict1['Boys'],dict1['Girls'])]
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dt = {'Boys': [72, 68, 70, 69, 74], 'Girls': [63, 65, 69, 62, 61]}
out = [dict(zip(dt.keys(), x)) for x in zip(*dt.values())]
print(out)
```